# Encoding String to "modified UTF-8" for the DataInput

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, arrays

I would like to encode String value to the modified UTF-8 format bytes. Something like

```
byte[] bytes = MagicEncoder.encode(str, "modified UTF-8");
DataInput input = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
```

Each read*() method of the DataInput has to be able to properly read the underlaying bytes.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to encode String into byte[] compatible with modified UTF-8 format? So that read methods of the DataInput class can read the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DataOutputStream`

```
   ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(byteOutputStream);
   dataOutputStream.writeUTF("some string to write");
   dataOutputStream.close();
```

result is available in `byteOutputStream.toByteArray()`

Comment: Sorry I just realized that my question is rather wrong. What I meant by String value is any Java primitive type represented as String and String as well. writeUTF() will work only for String. I need something more "generic". Something that will take the String representation and transform it to byte[]. I would like to achieve similar results as the byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(String); (http://sourceforge.net/projects/iharder/files/base64/2.3/). But without the at least 4 characters limitation. Sorry for my mistake. I am marking your answer as correct one, as you indeed answered the question.

Comment: You can use `String.valueOf()` to get the String for primitive types.

Comment: Getting the String value of the primitive is not the issue. The issue is if I do this:
// following your answet
dataOutputStream.writeUTF(intAsStr);
dataOutputStream.close();
decodedValue = byteOutputStream.toByteArray();
input = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedValue));
int x = input.readInt(); // this throws java.io.EOFException

Comment: If you want to use DataInputStream.readInt you must write the value with DataOutputStream.writeInt

Answer (score 0):

***As info:***

The modified UTF-8 encoding simply replaces the nul character U+0000, normally encoded as byte 0, as the byte sequence C0 80, the normal multi-byte encoding, used for codes > 0x7F.
*(Hence normal UTF-8 decoding suffices.)*

```
byte[] originalBytes;
int nulCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < originalBytes.length; ++i) {
    if (originalBytes[i] == 0) {
        ++nulCount;
    }
}

byte[] convertedBytes = new byte[originalCount + nulCount];
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < originalBytes.length; ++i, ++j) {
    convertedBytes[j] = originalBytes[i];
    if (originalBytes[i] == 0) {
        convertedBytes[j] = 0xC0;
        ++j;
        convertedBytes[j] = 0x80;
    }
}
```

Better to use System.arrayCopy, and check whether nulCount == 0.

Comment: It does not only treat NUL differently. It also allows encoding UTF-16 surrogates as if they were code points.

Comment: @PaulGroke thanks, I was not aware of that. _Clean life probably._